# What is this arithmetic function?

Tags: nt.number-theory

What is the name of the following "prime partition" function $\nu : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$?

$\nu(n)$ = number of distinct ways of writing $n$ as a sum of prime numbers

For example:

$\nu(1) = 0$

$\nu(2) = 1 = \nu(3) = \nu(4)$

$\nu(5) = 2$

Has it been investigated somewhere - its generating function in particular?

Ditto for the companion function $\nu_1$ which allows 1 to appear as an addend as well. It grows much faster than $\nu$, of course.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000607

Answer (score 6):

See Vaughan: [On the number of partitions into primes](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-007-9037-5), Ramanujan J. 15 (2008), 109-121. See also this [corrigendum](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-017-9929-y) and the related post [Wrong asymptotics of OEIS A000607 (number of partitions of an integer in prime parts)?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180858/wrong-asymptotics-of-oeis-a000607-number-of-partitions-of-an-integer-in-prime-p).